# Couldn't find an alternative telinit implementation to spawn in DOCKER while starting MarkLogic application in CENTOS7

Tags: docker, marklogic

I am running a docker file in windows 11 which will do two operations by running two scripts parallelly. So there are 2 bash scripts to do these 2 operations-

1. Install an application MarkLogic in CentOS7 (marklogicinstall.sh)
2. Deploy some files in the application server (deploy.sh)

I have written a wrapper script which commands to first run the script1, then the second1
However, I get this below error where the first script ends and before the second one starts-

```
Couldn't find an alternative telinit implementation to spawn.
```

The installation script which is marklogicinstall.sh is like this -

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get any CentOS updates then clear the Docker cache
#install yum by rpm 
#yum -y update && yum clean all

# Install MarkLogic dependencies
yum -y install glibc.i686 gdb.x86_64 redhat-lsb.x86_64 && yum clean all

# Install the initscripts package so MarkLogic starts ok
yum -y install initscripts && yum clean all


# Install MarkLogic then delete the .RPM file if the install succeeded
yum -y install MarkLogic.rpm && rm MarkLogic.rpm
printf "Marklogic installation done"

# Set the Path
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/MarkLogic/mlcmd/bin"

exec /usr/sbin/init
service /etc/init.d/MarkLogic start
```

Is it a problem with the start command?

Comment: Docker containers don't usually run init systems, so tools like `service`, `telinit`, and so on generally just don't work in Docker.  I'd get rid of the `initscripts` installation and the `service ... start`, command, and instead make the image's `CMD` launch the service as a foreground process; it will be the only thing running in its container (which is the normal Docker setup).

Comment: I am actually running a wrapper script from the CMD command of docker file which contains 2 bash scripts. One to install the MarkLogic application and the other to deploy files in the application server.

Comment: If I rather try to install the application directly from the docker, in that case I need to say the CMD to run my second script (deployment script) after starting the application which it does not do, it starts the application but stops it as soon my second script starts. I don't know how to resolve that so tried this above option. Can you please help me to know how I can run attach the second script to run from the dockerfile . I was using this in the CMD - CMD /etc/init.d/MarkLogic start && ./deploytde.sh && tail -f /dev/null

Comment: A Docker container runs a single process.  How would you do this without Docker, _in a single process_?  Do you need another container to do the initialization sequence, in the same way you'd frequently run database migrations from a separate container than the main database-server container?

Comment: There is a lovely writeup about this from a few years ago.  I just went through the steps with ML10 without any hiccups.  Perhaps it will help.

https://www.marklogic.com/blog/building-a-marklogic-docker-container/

Comment: @DavidMaze , I intend to run two services in one container. It's like running multiple scripts in one container. I do not want to separate the container as I already tried it, and the result is the deployment was unsuccessful as it was unable to find the port on which my first script has installed the application.

Comment: @DavidEnnis__17llamas__: I have read this, but I do not have need to create the cluster now. As I am doing the two operations in one server. The first service would install the application on a localhost IP and the second will deploy some files in that application which was installed and started by the first script.

Comment: i was not suggesting a cluster. That's a separate part of the blogpost.. The first couple of hundreds of lines is about creating an image.  IN the end of the  section "Creating a Container", once you have it up and running on an image with ML installed, then install your app  and use docker commit to a new name.  instead of trying to do the install *inside* of the docker build logic, use docker CLI to build the image you want in steps:
 - initial install ML 
 - then ML configured (commit with new tag)
 - deploy your own code (commit with new tag)

Comment: @DavidEnnis__17llamas__ : I have actually referred this same blog and my code is exact replica of what is there in it. Just that instead of creating cluster I am doing deployment after installation and for that I am running a new bash script which is called in the CMD after MarkLogic starts. And I am also using this command to build and run the docker: docker build -t dockerwithmultiops . ;; docker run -it --name=dockerwithmultiops -p 8000-8002:8000-8002 dockerwithmultiops:latest

Comment: Are you talking about linking containers? Like creating multiple containers and linking with the previous ones perhaps to use the same servers to do same tasks. Not sure of exactly what do you mean in your comment

Comment: Perhaps step back and state what you are trying to accomplish as a whole rather than what you tried that did not work.  What is the end state that you are trying to reach?

Comment: My requirement is to: 1. Install the MarkLogic application on CentOS machine by running a docker file. 
2. Deploy some files in the installed MarkLogic application. 
Both the operations would be carried out in a single container.

Comment: I have tried the following things -
1. Create a wrapper script (written two bash scripts one to install MarkLogic , second for the deployment). In the CMD command of the docker file I have executed the wrapper script which runs the first script (installation) but when it starts the second script it abruptly stops the first script. This is the problem.

Comment: 2. Also I have tried to run the installation from CMD in dockerfile and then run the deployment from a separate script. That does not work as well. As when the second script starts to run, the Marklogic server stops running.